# Always attach PGP public key to outgoing emails

Tags: mutt, neomutt

I'd like to always attach my PGP public key to outgoing emails, regardless of encryption/signing status. My vague hope is to encourage recipients to use it, or to get a dialog popup from their mail client to import it & encrypt future emails.

To do this manually, type `ESC`+`k` in the compose window and choose your key ID.

How can this be automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a macro to override the shortcut `y` for `send-message`.

```
macro compose y "<attach-key>`echo DJG53DFL...`<enter><enter><send-message>"
```

Echoing the ID of the PGP key allows narrowing down the `attach-key` dialog options so that a double `<enter>` effectively selects the proper key.